# What are the security issues with letting users upload videos and text documents?

Tags: security, file-upload

I want to let users (i.e. anyone who signs up for an account) upload and download video and text documents.  I have been researching the security issues regarding letting users upload files, but everything I can find on the subject assumes that users will only upload images.

Are there any security issues specific to letting users upload videos and text documents?  Is security a lot more difficult when users can upload files at video size?  Are there any particular file extensions I should look out for?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this: If you let users upload videos, images and text files, some of them will try to upload viruses, server-side scripts and other malicious code. Such code will then expose your site's users to what ever 'bad things' those users uploaded, within the context of your own site.

If you allow such uploads, you must be very careful that you are only saving files of the actual types you planned on - and not by looking at the file extension, either. You also must make sure those files are placed in locations where execute/script permissions are disabled.

Virus checking is a must - but it is **not at all enough**. A PHP script may not set off virus warnings at all, but that same script could reveal vital information for your site, or cause other bad things to happen if executed.

You must examine the content of the files - **never** rely on the extension or MIME type reported by the client. Those can easily be faked.

Answer (score 1):

Serve your downloads from a location for which you have disabled the execution of server side code. This is all you need to do to protect yourself from server side exploits. Relying on file extensions or other such things are all hacks.

If you want to fully protect your users (and indirectly your website) as well, you'll need to run the files through a suitable virus scanner. It is possible, and there are real-life examples of doing so, to exploit video decoders and such software to run arbitrary code. But if you start walking down that line, you could also argue that certain text strings might set off weird behavior in certain software, and that starts getting silly. Luckily, the people who write virus scanners will have done most of the work for you. So:

1. Never execute that what is uploaded
2. If you feel it's needed, virus scan them as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can virus check each file that is uploaded. If you look at most web based email clients you will see when you upload a file they are checked by McWhoever. In generally you shouldn't let them upload exe files but checking the extension is a very basic (unreliable) method.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to make an upload REALLY secure.

There are quite a lot of things to check - the file extension is just one part of it. Here are few things which have to be at least checked:

- file extension (as you've already mentioned)
- mimetype
- filesize
- depending on the users: maybe check the uploads with ClamAV ...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question here is a meta attack:

1. bad guy uploads a binary to your
   server, perhaps tricking your
   filters by compressing file and
   changing extension to .avi
2. exploit bug in a CGI script to
   decompress avi from #1
3. exploit bug in another CGI to
   execute file from #2 -> backdoor
   installed
4. backdoor accessed and rootkit
   installed to hide all evidence of steps
   1,2,3

Some variation on the above is what typically happens when servers are compromised.